# exception if JSON key is unknown?

Tags: .net, json

Lets say I have this JSON string

```
{"name": "myname", "id":12345, "passs":"configpass"}
```

Now passs is a typo. I'd like my serialization code (I can use json.net or the built in one in system.web) to throw an exception if it has a key (passs) which is not in my class. This way silly typos doesn't cause frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) serializer you can use the [MissingMemberHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) in the [JsonSerializerSettings](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

```
[TestFixture]
public class JsonTests
{
    [TestCase(@"{""name"": ""myname"", ""id"":12345, ""passs"":""configpass""}", ExpectedException = typeof(JsonSerializationException))]
    [TestCase(@"{""name"": ""myname"", ""id"":12345, ""pass"":""configpass""}")]
    public void TestName(string arg1)
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(
            new JsonSerializerSettings {MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error});
        Credentials credentials = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Credentials>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(arg1)));
    }
}

public class Credentials
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This also assumes you are using the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) serializer.